# How to send data to WebSocket API in Grafana?

Tags: python, websocket, grafana

I read the doc from Grafana (https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/golioth-websocket-datasource/?tab=overview) but when I try to replicate it by myself using my locally established WebSockets, it fails to receive data.

Here is what I did:

```
# ----------- server side: server.py-----------
import asyncio
import websockets
async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        message = "I got your message: {}".format(message)
        await websocket.send(message)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 8765))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

# ----------- client side: client.py-----------
import asyncio
import websockets
async def hello(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("hello world")
        print("< HELLO WORLD")
        while True:
            recv_text = await websocket.recv()
            print("> {}".format(recv_text))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello('ws://localhost:8765'))
```

Run `server.py` first and then `client.py`，`client.py` has the output as below：

```
< Hello world!
> I got your message: Hello world!
```

I also configured the host `ws://localhost:8765` in Grafana, I suspect I could receive 'hello world'. but didn't receive any data. (table view is toggled)

[image]

[image]

Wonder if anyone could help?

Comment: You have some error, so it looks like client is not connected. Click on the red exclamation mark in the panel corner for error message. Use browser console/websocket inspection and inspect connection/responses.

Comment: Does it mean this way should work?